# Vugen scripting using http protocol

Tags: loadrunner, vugen

I recorded a new script which is very large containing 20k lines including **extra files(lrw_custom_body.h)** i need to do like 300+ correlations in this script for dynamic values. In extra files(lrw_custom_body.h) the ending of the line is splitted up and coming in next line. For example: i need to do correlation for 12345678. But I'm getting like 1234" in one end of the line and in next starting line I'm getting remaining values like "5678. So, if i replace 12345678 this particular scenario is getting replaced cause it is **1234""5678** as it is coming in next line. Also the placement of "" is varying like 12""345678. So, not possible to find a combination considering 300+ dynamic values. As I mentioned earlier I have to do 300+ correlations having nearly 10k line this is tedious process to go to each line and remove "" and make it those values as a single continuous values. Is there any way I can quickly do this? Or any settings that can avoid this kind of things? Please suggest some ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Construct a custom correlation rulew which covers the items in question.   Regenerate the script from your recording with the new rule active.

And....this is why you get the big bucks.

Answer (score 0):

First remove unwanted requests to filter and then look.

Comment: There is no unwanted requests. In single API body itself having 2000+ lines of Jason it is save API so I can't remove it.